# Unable to inspect $_SESSION array variables with Xdebug in VSCode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I set up Xdebug for PHP in my VSCode today. It's all good so far but for some reason, all my variables in the `$_SESSION` array are shown as `null` (or `can not get property` in the watch list). But my script works as expected, the `$_SESSION` array is filled with correct variables.

I can even see the `$_SESSION` array being created at the time I start my session. And for example, one relevant variable `$user_id` (which is present at the time the session is being started in that script) is then showing up in the variables list, once it's accessed in the code - but shown as `null`.

I am suspecting it has something to do with how I start my session. This is how I do it:

1. This is the start of my `debugged script`:

   ```php
   <?php
   // Parts Inventory Page
   $basename = basename(__FILE__);
   $title = 'Parts Inventory';
   require_once('head.html');
   ```
2. This is the first line of the `head.html`:

   ```php
   <?php include 'session.php'; ?>
   ```
3. Finally, in `session.php` the session gets started:

   ```php
   <?php
   // Initiate session or not initiate sesstion - that is the question!

   // Start session if not started yet
   if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
       session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', true, true);
       session_start();
   }

   // This is not index.php
   if ($basename != 'index.php') {
       // User already logged in
       if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
           $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
       }
       // User not logged in and not index.php, so redirect him there
       else {
           header("Location: /PartHub/index.php?redirect=1");
       }
   }
   // This is index.php
   else {
       if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
           $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
       }
       // Make them click one of the buttons by showing the modal
       else {
           if ($_GET['redirect']) {
               $show_modal = 1;
           }
       }

   }
   ?>
   ```

Could any of this be the reason why Xdebug can't access the `$_SESSION` array variables? Again, the code works perfectly, I would just like to set up proper debugging for the future.